# Error: "java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format" when interpreting gzip response body from API

Tags: java, encoding, gzip, java-http-client

At the moment I am attempting to make simple get calls to a mediawiki-based API, specifically liquipedia.net. Within their terms of use they require that gzip encoding be accepted, and upon printing the response headers as well as the status code, I can asses that my call is successful. However, the response body prints an unintelligible blurb of characters which I don't know how to interpret. I attempted to integrate some methods of decompressing the info, as I assumed that the information I'm receiving may still be within .GZ form, however the methods I have used usually provide errors that state that the data is not within gzip form or nothing is done with the info whatsoever.

Here's the base method which establishes the connection, and attempts to simply print the response information.

```
public static void GET(String address) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create(address))
    .header("Accept-Encoding", "Gzip")
    .header("User-Agent", "RosterBot")
    .GET()
    .build();

    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
    HttpHeaders responseHeader = response.headers();

    
    System.out.println(responseHeader.toString());
    System.out.println(response.statusCode());



    System.out.println(decompress(response.body().getBytes()));
    
}
```

Here is a compression method which I used, and saw some others using

```
public static byte[] compress(final String str) throws IOException {
  
    System.out.println(b.toString());
    if ((str == null) || (str.length() == 0)) {
      return null;
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream obj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(obj);
    gzip.write(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    gzip.flush();
    gzip.close();

    return obj.toByteArray();
  }
```

As well as the decompression method

```
public static String decompress(final byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
    
    
    
    final StringBuilder outStr = new StringBuilder();
    if ((compressed == null) || (compressed.length == 0)) {
      return "";
    }
     
      final GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed));
      final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, "UTF-8"));

      String line;
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        outStr.append(line);
      }
    
    return outStr.toString();
  }
```

Here's an example of a response body I regularly obtain

> %�1� ��lM!��^aag,/J�p��w
> w��^d{p-���f�
> 4��}�����Z

As well as the response headers I receive

> { {:status=[200], accept-ranges=[bytes], age=[0], cache-control=[private, must-revalidate, max-age=0], content-disposition=[inline; filename=api-result.json], content-encoding=[gzip], content-type=[application/json; charset=utf-8], date=[Sat, 05 Jun 2021 23:56:40 GMT], referrer-policy=[no-referrer-when-downgrade], server=[nginx], vary=[Accept-Encoding, Treat-as-Untrusted, Cookie], via=[1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.5)], x-cache=[MISS], x-content-type-options=[nosniff], x-frame-options=[DENY], x-xss-protection=[1; mode=block]} }

I imagine I might be missing something obvious, but as I'm a bit new to working with API's, I would appreciate any help that can be provided!

Comment: That's not a decompression method. That's just two different pieces of code jammed togehter that don't even compile. No attempt at decompression whatsoever. Just wrap a `GZIPInputStream` aorund the input stream of the response.

Comment: My apologies, it seems that somehow the full method did not copy over to the code snippet. I just updated it to reflect the full method.

Comment: Well that doesn't compile either, there is an `else` without `if`, but if it did it would certainly decompress this response's `Content-encoding: gzip` correctly and give you back the JSON it is stated to contain. So what's your question?

Comment: The issue is that it doesn't do that all, it simply either provides back the same garble of characters as I provided above or it provides non information like "[B@307f6b8c", which I know is not a correct response due to examples provided in API documentation. Or, it simply provides an error which states that it is "not in GZIP format".

Comment: No, the issue is that the code you posted doesn't compile, but that decompression code can never provide `[B@307f6b8c`, which is the result of calling `byte[].toString()`. The behavour you allege is impossible. Post the real code: and in particular post the code that is printing the response.

Comment: You may disregard the comment about returning the string "[B@307f6b8c", as now it only returns an error the error "java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format."

Comment: Then either that header doesn't belong to this response or it is lying to you. It clearly states `content-encoding=[gzip]`. Of course you shouldn't execute your decompression method if that header value isn't present. But you need to clean up your post. You've alleged two behaviours that cannot occur, and you've omitted the real behaviour that does occur.

Comment: The Api documentation states "Your client must accept gzip encoding (supply an "Accept-Encoding: gzip" HTTP header with every request)." So, at this point, I'm simply unsure of what I should try then.

Comment: It means that *if* the `content-encoding: gzip;` header *is present* you must decompress the response. It doesn't mean that the peer is obliged to GZIP every response.

Comment: I apologize that my code wasn't properly formatted and obscured the true functionality as my code is currently riddled with comments everywhere with everything I have tried which, when I deleted, created unnecessary crossfire on compiled code. The only error I obtain is what I documented in my third comment. To your last response, I am still unsure of what I should do considering that simply printing the response does nothing but produce an unintelligible string of characters, and my decompression method, which you alleged would theoretically decompress the response, presents an error.

Comment: Sigh. Don't add the `GZIPInputStream` unless the `Content-encoding: gzip` header is present. Leave everything else alone. But I think you should try your code without the `GZIPInputStream` unconditionally and see what happens: I'm wondering whether they aren't just sending you plaintext despite the GZIP header, in which case they are in violation of RFC2616 and you should complain vociferously to them, and don't take 'no' for an answer.

Comment: As a side note. you shouldn't hardcode `"UTF-8`. You should get the actual charset from the response headers.

Comment: And you still haven't fixed your question to include the exception, which after all is what it is about.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, and your willingness to keep going with this, I appreciate it. If I interpreted correctly, I attempted to remove GZIPInputStream, and the error is avoided of course but the return is simply the response body example I provided above.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by modifying the T (type) of my HttpResponse like so

```
HttpResponse<InputStream> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofInputStream());
```

Afterwards, I parsed the data with GZIPInputStream and output the information

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(response.body()));

    while (true) {
      int ch = reader.read();
      if (ch==-1) {
         break;
      }
      System.out.print((char)ch);
    }
```

Comment: This is a good solution. The error in your original code was converting raw bytes into String and back to raw bytes - as this is usually not a loss-less conversion, unless the bytes do represent a string and you know which charset to use. It would have worked had you used `ofByteArray()` instead - but of course, at the expense of buffering the whole gzip'ed content in memory.